# On generalized AM-GM inequalities

Tags: inequality, means

Given $a_1,\dots,a_n \in \mathbb{R^+}$, and $2\le k\le n$, do we have:

$$\frac{\sum_\limits\text{cyclic}\sqrt[k]{a_1\dots a_k}}{\binom{n}{k}}\le \frac{\sum_\limits\text{cyclic}\sqrt[k-1]{a_1\dots a_{k-1}}}{\binom{n}{k-1}}$$

For example:

$$\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{a_1a_2a_3}}{\binom{3}{3}}\le\dfrac{\sqrt{a_1a_2}+\sqrt{a_1a_3}+\sqrt{a_2a_3}}{\binom{3}{2}}\le \dfrac{a_1+a_2+a_3}{\binom{3}{1}}$$

Comment: That (almost) looks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin%27s_inequality.

Comment: @Macavity It is in fact a valid inequality.

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes, it's been edited to limit to positive reals.  Haven't checked the rest, will do later

Comment: @Macavity I was talking about the second part of your comment.

Comment: @QuangHoang That's what I said will do later. Not evident to me as trivial from the OP or from your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is true and follows from usual AM-GM. For example
$$\begin{aligned}&\sqrt[k]{a_2\cdots a_{k+1}}+\sqrt[k]{a_1a_3\cdots a_{k+1}}+\sqrt[k]{a_1a_2a_4\cdots a_{k+1}}+\cdots+\sqrt[k]{a_1a_2\cdots a_k}\\
&\ge (k+1)\cdot\sqrt[(k+1)k]{a_1^ka_2^k\cdots a_{k+1}^k}=(k+1)\cdot\sqrt[k+1]{a_1a_2\cdots a_{k+1}}.\end{aligned}\tag{1}$$

**Note**: the $m$-th term is $\sqrt[k]{\dfrac{a_1a_2\dots a_{k+1}}{a_m}}$.

The needed inequality follows by adding all similar inequalities.

---

Let's look at an example for $n=4,k=2$:
$$\begin{aligned}\sqrt{a_2a_3}+\sqrt{a_1a_3}+\sqrt{a_1a_2}&\ge 3\sqrt[3]{a_1a_2a_3},\\
\sqrt{a_2a_4}+\sqrt{a_1a_4}+\sqrt{a_1a_2}&\ge 3\sqrt[3]{a_1a_2a_4}\\
\sqrt{a_3a_4}+\sqrt{a_1a_4}+\sqrt{a_1a_3}&\ge 3\sqrt[3]{a_1a_3a_4}\\
\sqrt{a_3a_4}+\sqrt{a_2a_4}+\sqrt{a_2a_3}&\ge 3\sqrt[3]{a_2a_3a_4}
\end{aligned}$$
Each of the $2$nd root occurs $n-k=4-2$ times (which I incorrectly counted as $n-k+1$ in the comment).

---

So how do we know for sure in general? There are two ways to see that

1. The *precise* way: For each $i_1<i_2<\cdots <i_k$, $\sqrt[k]{a_{i_1}a_{i_2}\cdots a_{i_k}}$ occurs exactly in the inequalities for $a_{i_1},a_{i_2},\cdots a_{i_k},a_{\color{red}{h}}$ for each $\color{red}{h} \neq i_1,i_2,\dots, i_k$.
2. The *intuitive* way: By symmetry of the inequality (which is kinda hard to explain), because we are talking about totally symmetry of (1), the means of $k$-th roots must be larger than or equal to the mean of $(k+1)$-th roots.

   ---

**Big Edit** I just realized that the OP asked for *cyclic*, not *symmetric*, sum. Shame on me. But that obviously is *not* a valid inequality when $a_i$ are all equal, just as @Macavity originally mentioned.

For example, when $n=4, k=2$ and all $a_i=1$, the RHS is $1$ while the LHS is $4/6$.

Comment: For each $k+1$-tuple $a_{i_1},a_{i_2},\dots, a_{i_{k+1}}$ we have a similar inequality. Add them all up, the RHS gives the $(k+1)$ times of the $(k+1)$-th roots, while the LHS gives $n-k+1$ times of the $k$-th roots.

Comment: The problem is stated for cyclic sums. I am not seeing those in your LHS, in fact counting all possible tuples would give you symmetric sums. Not so clear, perhaps you can illustrate for $n=4, k=3$ vs $n=4, k=2$ to show how your counting works.

Comment: In your first equation, the second term is $\sqrt[k]{a_1a_3...a_{k+1}}$. That term **cannot** appear in a cyclic sum. The same error is illustrated in your e.g. You may be proving something interesting, but it certainly is not the question posed by the OP, which is about cyclic sums.

Comment: @Nemo let me fix that. It is written not as a cyclic sum, but rather *ordered* sum. The case $k=2$ is a little mis-leading.

Comment: Yes neither can $\sqrt{a_2a_4}$ appear in the cyclic sum. It's a symmetric sum you are putting down.  Sorry this looks wrong as a proof.

Comment: Strange thing is, I couldn't find a counter example easily.

Comment: @Macavity Yes, you are right (and were right). Cyclic sum doesn't work. I saw $\binom{n}{k}$ and *mean*, immediately thought of *symmetric* sum without noticing that the OP asked for *cylic* sum.

Comment: No problems, that was a good effort. I suspect the inequality works for $n=3$ but not higher.

Comment: Nice counter eg +1 for all the good work.